# Isabelle/HOL Question about Sets of Tuples

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I have a beginner's question about Isabelle/HOL:

I want to prove the following lemma:

`lemma 
  shows "{(x,y) . x ∈ {0..<n} ∧ y ∈ {0..<n} ∧ x = y} = {(x,x). x < n}"`

But the proof state is:

`proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. {(x, y). x ∈ {0..<n} ∧ y ∈ {0..<n} ∧ x = y} = {(xa, x). x < n}`

Why did the xa appear and how can I define the set the right (succinct) way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(x,y)` in the set comprehension `{(x,y). ....}` is *binding variable names*. As you write `{(x,x). x < n}`, you bind *two* variables named `x`, where the second `x` [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the first.

`{(x,x). x < n}` is just a nice syntax for a lambda term, actually. Internally, it translates to `Collect (case_prod (λx. λx. x < n))`. Looking at the term this way, the shadowing is more obvious.

To fix your problem, you have to explicitly express the information that the first and the second bound variable are to be identical, that is: `{(x1,x2). x1 = x2 ∧ x1 < n}`.

As a side note: The lemma you are trying to show is not true. (For example, `n` could be an `int`.) If you want `n` to be a `nat`, you have to make this explicit, for example by giving a type in your goal like this `{(x,y). x ∈ {0..<(n::nat)} ∧ y ∈ {0..<n} ∧ x = y} = {(x1,x2). x1 = x2 ∧ x1 < n}`.

Especially, if you are a beginner, I would strongly suggest to introduce free variables in lemma heads explicitly with the syntax `lemma Name: fixes n :: ‹nat› assumes ‹...› shows ‹...›`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, I understand the problem now.

I used fixes n::nat but removed it to give a minimal example :)

Comment: I'm happy that my answer is of help to you, Diana! You can “accept” my answer to let other people know in overviews that your problem has been solved. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: `{(x,x) |x. x < n}` should also work. The `|x' specifies the variables to be quantified over explicitly.